# why can't I find module ‘Vision.Image.Storage.DevIL?

Tags: image, haskell

I installed the friday package (friday-0.2.1.1)for Haskell, but when I tried to run the resize_image example could I got this error;

Could not find module ‘Vision.Image.Storage.DevIL’

..does anybody know what the problem might be?

Comment: Did you install `friday-devil` also : https://hackage.haskell.org/package/friday-devil ?

Comment: obs, I thought I did, but that fails because Missing C library: IL. Seems a mess so I will try another image package handling instead.

Comment: @hotGopher That probably means that you just need to install the C library DevIL before installing the Haskell package friday-devil.

Comment: It also needs the relevant C library. In case you are in Ubuntu, these commands are likely to install them `sudo apt-get install libdevil-dev libdevil1c2`

Comment: i am on mac, but thank you both:)